# MFA prompt frequency in Firebase Auth with Identity Platform

Tags: firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

Is there a way to configure the MFA prompt frequency in Firebase Authentication (with Identity Platform)?

I would like to have the 2nd factor checked only at given intervals not every login but found nothing in the docs.

I am using the firebase SDK to enroll and login in JS.